# Postgres ActiveRecord limit table size to one row

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, sinatra

I am creating a custom CMS using `Sinatra` and `Postgres` with `sinatra-activerecord` enabled. I am creating a model called `SiteInfo` which will store information such as the `about_description`, `about_photo`, `tagline`, etc. Is there a way within the migration to create that `SiteInfo` table to specify that there can only be *one* row? There's no way through the interface for the admin or user to create an additional one, I'm just wondering.

Comment: So you want `about_description`, `about_photo` and `tagline` to all be stored in the same column for each `SiteInfo` record?

Comment: Just for clarification: In the title you ask "..to one ROW", but in the question you state "...only be one COLUMN". I suspect you mean Rows?

Comment: @Manuel updated question! I want it so that there can only be *one* SiteInfo record (so only one row,yes). I already created one in the seeds file and in the case of this app there is no way through the UI to create an additional SiteInfo record I'm just wondering out of curiosity how I would go about doing that if I ever *needed* to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question: No, you can't, and there is no need for.

You'll want to do something like `SiteInfo.first` to load your information anyway.